# If I insert data into table which is already bucked and have data. How this insert works?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have one table which is created and I have inserted data into the table again I am trying to insert data into same table. How it is going to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how you can insert data into hive:
1. Inserting data from file to hive table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/file.txt' into table hiveTableName;
```

2. Inserting data from another table to hive table using normal and overwrite method:

   i. INSERT INTO TABLE HiveTable1 select * from HiveTable2;
   ii. INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE HiveTable1 select * from HiveTable2;

Here the difference overwrite will erase all previous data and insert new data, normal insert will append the new data to old data.

Same applies for bucketed table, the table updates with new bucketed data and stores in the namenode.
Hope this helps, any changes do let me know.